# Sort multimap by values after keys have been sorted

Tags: c++

```
multimap <int, string> mm; 

(1, A),
(2, B),
(3, D),
(3, C)
```

I was able to get some data in numerical order using multimap keys, but in the case of duplicates, I would like the values to be in order as well.

```
(1, A),
(2, B),
(3, C),
(3, D)
```

What's the easiest way of doing this? Seeing as to how maps only sort by key, I would think I would have to make a set of some sort, but am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: How about a set of pairs?

Comment: You can define your own `compare` function and sort them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two reasonable solutions---pick the one that makes more sense.

If you view the `int` as a key and the `string` as a value, but a key can be mapped to multiple values---in other words, if you view two pairs with the same `int` as being part of the same "group" and you might want to iterate through a specific group easily, then use a `map<int, multiset<string> >`.

If you view each `int`, `string` pair as distinct, and some pairs just might *happen* to have the same `int`, then you want a `multiset<pair<int, string> >`.

In the case that duplicate pairs (both `int` and `string` are the same) should not be present, these become `map<int, set<string> >` and `set<pair<int, string> >` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Put your `multimap` into a `set<pair<int, string>>`.